# Working with UTC and php

Tags: php, time, utc

I'm using Live Connect to create calendar events.  According to their docs, the start_time given for an event should indicate how many hours off the time is from UTC (i.e. +0700 or -0300).  As a first stab , I've got some code that works, pieced together from the php manual.  However, it "feels" pretty verbose.  So, from a stylistic point of view, might there be a way to clean up what I've got into something more succinct? Note that the $time_zone is something that I know based on a given user.

```
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($time_zone);
$dateTime= new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZone);
$gmt_offset = ($dateTime->getOffset())/3600;
$negative = ($gmt_offset<0);
$gmt_offset = abs($gmt_offset);
if ($gmt_offset < 10) {
$gmt_offset = '0'.$gmt_offset.'00';
} else {
    $gmt_offset = $gmt_offset.'00';
}
if ($negative) {
    $gmt_offset = '-'.$gmt_offset;  
} else {
$gmt_offset = '+'.$gmt_offset;
}
```

Thank you for your input.

-Eric

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but I feel there's way too much math involved and that the DateTime class can handle this for you.

Comment: As an example, I live in the Pacific Northwest, so my $gmt_offset is -7 (using the Datetime class).  But I need to change it to the form "-0700" for Live Connect purposes, hence all of the extra code.  I was hoping that "-0700" is some type of standard format so that I could somehow use a pre-defined class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$gmt_offset = $dateTime->format('O');
```

From the [PHP manual page for `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> **format character**: O
>   **Description**: Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours
>   **Example returned values**: Example: +0200

Comment: Thank you!  Is it corny for me to say that I really do love PHP?